# Illegal to inject a message body into a singleton into public org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider

Tags: java, linux, centos, resteasy, jboss6.x

I am implementing Web Services with "resteasy" running on JBOSS Server 6.0.0

```
The JARS used in the application are :
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jboss-vfs.jar

resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.2.final.jar
resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.5.final.jar
resteasy-jaxrs.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final.jar
scannotation-1.0.2.jar
servlet-api.jar
```

The application is running perfectly on Windows 7 OS with JAVA 1.6.26 Version on JBOSS Server 6.0.0.

When the application is deployed to LINUX CENTOS with JAVA 1.6.34 on JBOSS Server 6.0.0 , it throws the following errors :

Illegal to inject a message body into a singleton into public org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider

Unable to Instantiate MessageBodyReader

Failing to Instantiate Listener

Can anyone let me know where am I going wrong or should I need to add something.

Comment: Is your auto-scanning enabled (resteasy.scan) ? If so, try disabling it  and register your RESTEasy service manually in web.xml as presented here:  http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/illegal-to-inject-a-message-body-into-a-singleton-into-public-org-codehaus-jackson-jaxrs-jacksonjsonprovider/

Comment: @Laurentiu I have tried this long back.. The issue comes only when I deploy the war to LINUX OS with JBOSS 6.0.0.. I somehow feel that I am missing some jar or library..

Comment: Try experimenting with various jackson and resteasy versions. And see if you really need both resteasy-jaxrs.jar and resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final.jar. It seems to me they are the same thing, only the first may be an older version. I've read that "This is actually a problem with the Jackson implementation.  The JAX-RS specification states that the JAX-RS runtime must pick a Provider constructor with the greatest number of parameters.  The problem is, Resteasy does not know how to resolve and inject the parameters of the Jackson provider constructor with the most parameters."

Comment: @Laurentiu Thanks alot for your suggestions. It is working now. The problem was with the versions of jars I have used.